# Numpy replace previous n elements if current condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of boolean:

```
x = np.array([
    False,  False,  False,  True, True, False,  True, False, 
    False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, True,
])

array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False,  True])
```

For every True value, I want to set the previous n values (eg n=2) to True. Is there an efficient way to do it? I tried using loops but I think it is not the most efficient way.

output:

```
array([False, True, True,  True,  True, True,  True, True, True,
            True, False, False, False, True, True,  True])
```

One way I thought of is to get the mask of all the previous 2 values of any True value, and then do a np.logical_or with the original array, but I can't seem to get the first part right!

Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: `x[np.maximum(np.flatnonzero(x) - n, 0)[:,None] + np.arange(n)] = True`, IIUC.

Comment: This works and I have to spend some time figuring out how it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` to get the index of True, then get the indexes of previous n values before the True with list comprehension. Finally, replace the values.

```
# Change the boolean to int and do np.where

x = x.astype('int')
condition = np.where(x == 1)[0]
prev_n = 2

# Find the indexes of n-previous values
result = [i - number for number in range(1, prev_n+1) for i in condition]

# Replace the values
x[result] = 1
x = x.astype('bool')

array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am trying to avoid looping!